# how to use jquery to find an input element with single class

Tags: javascript, jquery

If an input element has multiple classes assigned as below(form-control and hide). How can we find it using single class

e.g. `<tr id="10"><td><input class="form-control hide" name="[0].Items" type="number" value="1" /></td></tr>`

I've tried the following but it does not work

```
 $('tr#10').find("input[class='hide']").addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
```

but the following does work

```
$('tr#10').find("input[class='form-control hide']").addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
```

But I don't want to use find with multiple classes

Comment: `$('tr#10 input.hide')`

Comment: pretty sure the bracket form of selecting is looking for a string, so you would need the exact string to match. Why not use `input.hide`?

Comment: You shouldn t add the type of tag in the selector, #10 is better than tr#10. For the answer, see imgonzalves and shan robertson's comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('tr#10 input.hide').toggleClass('show hide');
```

> http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

If you insist on using the attribute selector, it has to be this:

```
$("tr#10 input[class~='hide']").toggleClass('show hide');
```

which matches input elements amongst whose classes is an exact match 'hide'.

> https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Simpy refer to the desired classes with a `.`

```
$('tr#10').find(".form-control")
```

or

```
$('tr#10').find(".hide")
```

or

```
$('tr#10').find(".form-control.hide")
```